# cross android pc java graphics interface

Tags: java, android, swing

Is there a UI package that works on both Android and desktop Java? I am wondering if a package exists that can either be handed a window or activity and will display user defined graphics with a identical interface on both Android and a PC.

The end goal is to have code that works both on android and a PC with very minor to no modification either way. A tool such as Bluestack is not what I am looking for because it requires installation on the users end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that JGame was more or less what I was looking for. It runs fine on both desktop java and android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.
You can install the android sdk + emulator and run the apk on the desktop, but then you have already expressed your wish not to install anything on the client side.
Considering your requirement (identical interface, minor to no modification, no user installation) I would say your best bet is a web application with a mobile view css.